# Что делает следующая строчка?

Tags: c++, строки, память

Есть динамический массив под названием buffer, который хранит в себе строку в стиле С. (Например какое-нибудь предложение: Hello world)
Что делает данная строка? Высчитывает количество символов?

```
cout << (unsigned int*)buffer << endl;
```

Comment: Выведет указатель (в смысле адрес) на строку. Правда для этого лучше привести к void*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводит **адрес**, на который указывает `buffer`. Грубо говоря, где в памяти располагается эта строка.

Comment: Спасибо! Не хотелось бы вас мучать, но не могли бы мне объяснить почему именно  (unsigned int*) buffer, почему такой синтаксис. Как я понимаю, мы объявляем указатель который указывает на buffer?

Comment: Просто если выводить `cout << buffer`, то сработает та перегрузка оператора `<<`, которая для `char*` - а она считает, что нужно выводить строку в стиле С, а не адрес. `unsigned int*`, как мне кажется, выбран произвольно. Лично я бы написал `void*`. Указатель - указывает не на `buffer`, а туда же, куда указывает сам `buffer`.

Comment: В этом и есть суть, мне нужно показать ,что указатель указывает, туда где сам buffer. Это код из книги Сиддхартха Рао "С++ по одному часу в день". Хотелось просто самому все проверить

Comment: @Marat если я вас правильно понял, то это делается так: ```cout << &buffer;```